# Packaging renaming of account object

Tags: managed-package, standard-objects, customlabel

We've renamed Account object using 'Rename Tabs and Labels' from Setup menu to Customer. Everything works fine.

The problem appeared when we packed our application as managed package - after installation in client org original object name is used, i.e. it's still Account but not Customer.

Is there any special way how such object renaming should be put into package or is this just one more platform limitation, i.e. not feasible at all? How could we achieve this, any alternatives?

Comment: Consider that most customers will have many apps installed in their org plus local customisations. So (automated) renaming by one app will likely undermine the user experience in the other apps; my view is it is best to at most suggest the renaming and leave your customers to decide.

Comment: @KeithC It's sort of "one package per org" approach, i.e. package installation requirement is to allocate separate org for it, that's why we could do any sort of customization re standard objects, just need to find a way how to package it.

Comment: OK fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you need to use Translation Workbench to add a transaction for English rather than using "Rename Tabs and Labels".

Source - [Edit Labels of Managed Custom Objects (For translation)](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000IVON)

AS for the location to add a translation for [Accounts, in Account Name & Account Name (Local) in Translation Workbench](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h126AAA) it suggests doing so from under "Tab Names and Labels".

> You need to goto Customise->Tab Names and Label-> Select Chinese as Language->Click on Edit button Account and Click Next->Add/Modify Translation.

[image]

It seems a bit counter-intuitive that the transaction for a standard object is done from a similar location to the standard tab renaming, but that seems to be the implied solution. Of course, you would still be adding a transaction for English, not outright renaming the tab.

I assume that the tab translations can be packaged, where as the direct rename can't be.

Comment: Could you please give me a clue what's the name of the label which corresponds to account tab name. So far I've looked through all available things in Translation Workbench regarding Account object - there is nothing like name or tab or whatever. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like it is done under "Tab Names and Labels" for standard objects. I haven't done it in practice. So let me know how you get on.

Comment: @DanielBallinger While this is generally the correct procedure, I can't imagine that Salesforce would allow you to package translations on standard objects or fields.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you might want to be using [Trialforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/isv/2015/05/supercharge-your-salesforce-experience-with-trialforce-part-1.html). Using TF allows you to set up a template org *exactly* as you want it to appear (e.g. with your package installed, translations translated, etc) that can then be customized later. This would probably be a superior experience for customers, since the requirement is to create a new org for installation.